# Laravel: 2 models 1 controller

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, model, controller

Not necessarily Laravel-only related but, I'm working on a website where users can register and, if they want, they can subscribe to a paid plan.

If they don't subscribe, they can still navigate the website and see very limited content (just a few paragraphs of each article).

This website has two models: User and Plan. Initially the idea was to allow users to choose from multiple plans, however only one plan is being used: "Premium".

When they subscribe to a Plan they will stay on that plan until they change their mind and being charged every month.

I have a UserController with the following methods: index, create, store, show, edit, update and a UserPlanController with the same methods. When the user decides to cancel his subscription to a Plan, I just call UserPlanController::update() that basically changes the status from "active" to "cancelled". They might stay as free users or can also cancel their account (changing their user status from "active" to "cancelled" as well).

I've been requested to create a "Cancel" button for back office agents that will cancel the subscription to the paid plan and also cancel the user account (set both statuses to "cancelled"), but keeping the option to cancel the subscription only.

I was thinking of just create a new controller and cancel both things from it but I would prefer to avoid to duplicate the code to perform these two actions and I already have one controller for each resource, so do I need to create a third controller to do both actions?

The other option that I have in mind is to just make two ajax requests to both endpoints: Click on "Cancel" -> Ajax request to cancel the subscription -> Ajax request to cancel the user account but I'm not sure if this is just a "hacky" workaround.

Any help will be appreciated,

Thanks in advance

Comment: From my point of view I don't think that you need another controller instead of that you can do in UserController. Because this things are done by users.

Answer (score 1):

First you should have a model for you plans and for your users, which only deal with operations on these data structures.

The UserController uses the User model and the UserPlanController uses the Plan model (and/or the User model)

Now what you could do is, in the UserController:cancelUserAccount function you could check if the User has a plan, and cancel that as well.

```
use User;
use Plan;

class UserController {
    public function cancelAccount(Request $request, User $user){
        $plans = Plan::where('user_id', $user->id);
        foreach($plans as $plan){
            $plan->destroy();
        }

        $user->destroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @William Randokun. In the User controller I just have a update() method that can update any of the user fields (email, name and also the status). Do I need to create a separate method to cancel the account (which is basically changing the status from "active" to "cancelled")?

Comment: If your update() function only updates things on the User that is fine and you probably should keep it that way.

But you could create a new function combinedUpdate() where the User->update function is called, but also the code that handles the subscriptions. And then you can always use the combinedUpdate() method, if you always want to handle the plans as well when modifying a User.

Answer (score 0):

If the 2 controllers do the same methods, edit, update and you eliminate some of the one that they don't have access why not use a middleware ?

You can have one controller and define access with a middleware.

then you can assign the routes from one plan to that middleware and restrict the access there. you can even use route::groups for clear code.

```
php artisan make:middleware paid
```

on the handle method verify the user

on the route.php file.

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>array('web','paid')],function(){
   //paid members routes...
   Route::get ....
});

Route::group(['middleware'=>array('web')],function(){
   //regular members routes...
   Route::get ....
});
```

I think this will easier to maintain since you will have 1 controller for the methods, remove duplicate actions and more organize.